# Java add/remove at the same loop without ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I have a following Java code:

```
if (value instanceof Collection) {
    Collection collection = (Collection) value;
    Collection updatedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator iterator = collection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Object object = iterator.next();
        if (object instanceof String) {
            iterator.remove();
            updatedObjects.add(StringUtils.wrapInSingleQuotes((String) object));
        } else if (object instanceof Date) {
            iterator.remove();
            updatedObjects.add(((Date) object).getTime());
        }
    }
    collection.addAll(updatedObjects);
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code in a more efficient way in order to avoid new `ArrayList` allocation ? If so, please show an example.

Comment: Can you add the declaration of `collection`?

Comment: No, because I'm obtaining the object from an external system and it can contain any type.. like a plain wrapper.. like Integer or collection like in the example above.

Comment: You have to declare `collection` in order to use it. Something like `Collection collection`, even if you don't initialize it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have updated my question

Comment: Good. Do you know which subtype of `Collection` `collection` is? `List`, `Set`...? Which implementation (`ArrayList`, `HashSet`...)?

Comment: This is the biggest issue - I believe any of them. I can't control the process. Can only try to adjust the values based on a certain types. And I'm trying to avoid instanceof List,Set in order to do it in a more generic way

Comment: I see, can you do `instanceof` tests to learn what the external API returns and then rely on that in the future? I assume `value` is of type `Object`.

Comment: Yeah.. but I'm trying to avoid instanceof List, Set in order to do it in a more generic way

Comment: If you're worried about performance, a generic way might be in conflict. Besides, I'm suggesting you do these tests only now if you can assume that the same type always will be returned.

Comment: Well, let's test it for List or Set. Could you please show the effective solution(from the performance point of view) how to rewrite the code based on this approach ? Thanks!

Comment: If you cast to the List which guarantees that the collection is ordered, then you can update current index's value with the modified value by calling `E set(int index, E element);` on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Having `Collection` of different types is bad practice, anyway you can use Java 8 streams:

```
return collection.stream().map(object -> {
        if (object instanceof String) {
            return StringUtils.wrapInSingleQuotes((String) object);
        } else if (object instanceof Date) {
            return ((Date) object).getTime();
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also you can just avoid calling `iterator.remove()` and before the last line write

```
collection.clear();
collection.addAll...
```

If you want to update the value of the variable `collection` because is a parameter varialble, for example you can follow the logic in `java.util.List.sort` implementation.

```
    Object[] updatedObjects = collection.toArray();
    //fill the array updatedObjects 
    ListIterator<E> i = collection.listIterator();//this works only if collection is a list
    for (Object e : updatedObjects ) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, due to a complex underling logic(this is a dynamic builder of native Neo4j Cypher complex queries based on user input) I can't avoid such kind of code. Sorry for additional question but in regards of your solution - what is the more preferable way from a performance point of view - mine approach or yours ?